# Assume that $f$ is analytic and one-to-one on $\mathbb{D} = \{z : |z| < 1\}$ and $f(z) = z + z^2g(z),$ where $g$ is analytic in $\mathbb{D}.$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Assume that $f$ is analytic and one-to-one on $\mathbb{D} = \{z : |z| < 1\}$ and $f(z) = z + z^2g(z),$ where $g$ is analytic in $\mathbb{D}.$ Prove that if $f(\mathbb{D})⊂\mathbb{D}$ or $\mathbb{D}⊂f(\mathbb{D})$,then $g(z)=0$ for all $z ∈ \mathbb{D}$.

I got the first part.  It is easy using using Shwartz.  The $\mathbb{D}⊂f(\mathbb{D})$ I am having trouble with.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathbb{D}\subset f(\mathbb{D})$, since $f$ is injective, the function

$$h = f^{-1}\lvert_\mathbb{D}$$

satisfies all conditions with $h(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}$. So the second follows from the first.